# How to get the 1st child tag from the following XML through DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML and there is a `Children<Child>` tag and again `Children<Super Child>` tag is there for Parent `Children<Child>` as below -

```
<parent>
<children name="abhishek">
      <children type="5007"/>
 </children>
<parent>
```

Actually when I try to get the attribute through `getElementsByTagName("children")`, I am getting both the children as output with name `abhishek` where I am expecting the first children to come as my output.

How to achieve the same?

Comment: side note: the hierarchy seem to convoluted... it should be more like `<parent><children><child></child></children></parent>`, but anyways. Have you looked in [xom](http://xom.nu/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [expected behavior of getElementsByTagName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29). I'd recommend [using XPath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) to pick out the elements you want. It's much more expressive and reliable for selecting nodes out of XML.